# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_J7Ije/aiohttp/ when installing discord.py

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi3, discord.py, setup.py

Edit: Got it solved! Thanks to @Raz Kissos for much help and having patience with me, and others who answered! I am new to stackOverflow, any moderators may lock this thread if that is a thing, as I could not find it.

I am trying to install the discord.py library, but as doing so, i recieve this:

```
    Collecting discord.py
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/3c/2a97b47fd8839f8863241857bbd6a3998d1de1662b788c8d9322e5a40901/discord.py-0.16.12.tar.gz
Collecting aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0 (from discord.py)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/5a/7b81ea8729d41f44c6fe6a116e466c8fb884950a0061aa3768dbd6bee2f8/aiohttp-1.0.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-_J7Ije/aiohttp/setup.py", line 60, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+")
    RuntimeError: aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_J7Ije/aiohttp/
```

This happened when I used this command:

```
pip install -U discord.py
```

This in on a raspberry pi 3B+, using Raspbian OS.
If there is more information needed, I will provide :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try simply `pip install discord.py`?
Also check your python version and update it if needed since the exception raised is `aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+` so your python version might be lower.

Comment: Just tried ```pip install discord.py```, gave me ```Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-eaAMt6/aiohttp/``` (Pretty similar, but not identical in the path). And using python3.8 -V tells me my version is 3.8.0.

Comment: Do you have several python versions on your machine?

Comment: Not sure, how do i check/uninstall them?

Comment: sorry try `ls /usr/bin/python*` and it should show all the python interpreters.
If there are indeed several installations just specify with which python interpreter you will run pip: `python3 -m pip install discord.py`

Comment: ```/usr/bin/python   /usr/bin/python2.7         /usr/bin/python2-config  /usr/bin/python3.5         /usr/bin/python3.5m         /usr/bin/python3-config  /usr/bin/python3m-config
/usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python2.7-config  /usr/bin/python3         /usr/bin/python3.5-config  /usr/bin/python3.5m-config  /usr/bin/python3m        /usr/bin/python-config
```

Comment: try this: `python3 -m pip install discord.py --user`

Comment: hey man sorry to bother but can you please mark my answer as the final answer? I just want some stack overflow points :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the error specifies you do not use the correct python version, you should try checking if you have the required python version installed.
If you do and it still shows this error, perhaps you have multiple python installations on your machine. there is no need to worry, just specify which python interpreter you want to use:

```
<python interpreter> -m pip install <module name> --user
```

For example:

```
python3.8 -m pip install discord.py --user
```

This will add the discord.py module only to the `python3.8` interpreter so make sure to use it for running the code.

Comment: It did say it ```Successfully installed aiohttp-3.6.2 async-timeout-3.0.1 attrs-19.3.0 chardet-3.0.4 discord.py-1.3.4 idna-2.10 idna-ssl-1.1.0 multidict-4.7.6 typing-extensions-3.7.4.2 websockets-6.0 yarl-1.4.2```but when doing ```python3.8 filename.py```, it still will not find the module.

Comment: Use `python3` not `python3.8`, these are different interpreters. If you want to use `python3.8` you can simply run `python3.8 -m pip install <module name> --user`.
hopefully my edited answer can help...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
pip install -U discord.py
```

If that does not work:

```
pip3 install -U discord.py
```